# If $\{a_n\}$ is convex and bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Delta a_n=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that:

> If the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is convex and bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Delta a_n=0$.

By convex we mean $\Delta^2a_n\geq0$ where $\Delta^2a_n=\Delta(\Delta a_n)$ and $\Delta a_n= a_n-a_{n+1}$.

My attempt: Since $\{ a_n \}$ is convex and bounded, it implies that $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\Delta a_n$ converges. Also $\{a_n\}$ converges. But here I stop! I don't have any idea how to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Delta a_n=0$.

Comment: well you just have to show that $\Delta _n$ is decreasing then your result will follow

Answer (score 1):

From the convexity assumption you get that $(-\Delta_n)_n$ is a non-increasing sequence with eventually non-negative terms. In order to conclude just use the following remark.

**Claim.** If $b_n$ is non-increasing sequence of non-negative numbers and $\sum b_n$ converge then $nb_n \to 0$.

*Proof of the claim.* $(n-[n/2]+1)b_n = \sum_{k=[n/2]}^{n}b_n \leq \sum_{k=[n/2]}^{n}b_k =S_{n}-S_{[n/2]} \to 0$, as $S_n \to \ell := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$, hence the proof.

Comment: Thanks, but the proof of the claim is not so clear to me. Try to polish it please!

Comment: and now, is it ok?